# How to write a .htaccess for URL redirect or rewrite for WordPress site?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I am trying to understand regex URL rewrites and redirects.

I need the following:

`www.mydomain.com/tag/*/index.html` (for example, `mydomain.com/tag/winter-holidays/index.html` or `mydomain.com/tag/summer-holidays/index.html`) to redirect to: `www.mydomain.com/index.php/tag/WHATEVER/index.html`

`www.mydomain.com/*/` (for example, `www.mydomain.com/four-roots-of-happy-living/`, `www.mydomain.com/four-roots-of-happy-living` (without the ending slash), `www.mydomain.com/living/`, `www.mydomain.com/living` (without the ending slash) AND ALSO `www.mydomain.com/category/happiness/` and `www.mydomain.com/category/happiness` (without the ending slash) to redirect to `www.mydomain.com/index.php/WHATEVER/` or `www.mydomain.com/index.php/WHATEVER/ WHATEVER/`.

I have tried so many different combinations in my .htaccess file that my head is spinning now.

In my .htaccess (currently) I had this, but have deactivated it for the meantime until I can get this straight:

```
Redirect 301 /* /index.php/*

RedirectMatch 301 /*(.*)/? /index.php/$1
```

Note: My htaccess file was/is in my root directory, my WordPress site is in a wp folder off that, and it did not have a .htaccess file.

Comment: update... i have this in file now, and it omosrtly working, but not for urls ending in a slag. which should be sinplke.. but man, this is kiling me:

Comment: #301 Redirect Old File

#Redirect 301 /* /index.php/*
Redirect 301 /*/? /index.php/


#301 Redirect Entire Directory

RedirectMatch 301 /*(.*)/? /index.php/$1